# Service Broker "Broker Enabled" option goes from true to false when performing backup/restore of DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

We have two production servers joined by an AAG, and for a specific database, the Service Broker is enabled (Options -> Service Broker -> Broker Enabled : true. We use this for SignalR.

However, every time I perform a backup and then restore the database on a test environment, I have to manually enable the broker again (`ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`), as it's disabled when the database has been restored on the test server.

Can any option be set when performing either the BACKUP or RESTORE command that retains this database option? I use a script for generating the BACKUP/RESTORE statements, but I don't understand why a specific database option goes from true to false just by performing a BACKUP/RESTORE. Here are examples of the BACKUP and RESTORE commands I generate:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DatabaseName] TO DISK = 'B:\backups\full_DatabaseName_20200902_1.bak', DISK = 'B:\backups\full_DatabaseName_20200902_2.bak', DISK = 'B:\backups\full_DatabaseName_20200902_3.bak', DISK = 'B:\backups\full_DatabaseName_20200902_4.bak' WITH COPY_ONLY, NOFORMAT, CHECKSUM, INIT, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION, STATS = 10, BLOCKSIZE=65536

RESTORE DATABASE [DatabaseName] FROM DISK = 'B:\backups\full_DatabaseName_20200902_1.bak', DISK = 'B:\backups\full_DatabaseName_20200902_2.bak', DISK = 'B:\backups\full_DatabaseName_20200902_3.bak', DISK = 'B:\backups\full_DatabaseName_20200902_4.bak' WITH FILE=1,MOVE N'DatabaseName_data' TO N'E:\Data\DatabaseName.mdf',MOVE N'DatabaseName_log' TO N'F:\Logs\DatabaseName.ldf',MOVE N'DatabaseName_index' TO N'E:\Data\DatabaseName.ndf',MOVE N'DatabaseName_data_io' TO N'f:\Data\DatabaseName_io.ndf', NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10, RECOVERY, REPLACE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can any option be set when performing either the BACKUP or RESTORE command that retains this database option?

Edit: you can [restore the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-arguments-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#service_broker_with_options) with `ENABLE_BROKER`. Check the sample below:

```sql
RESTORE DATABASE [WideWorldImportersA] 
FROM  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\WideWorldImporters-Full.bak'
WITH  FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'WWI_Primary' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\SB\WideWorldImporters.mdf'
,  MOVE N'WWI_UserData' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\SB\WideWorldImporters_UserData.ndf'
,  MOVE N'WWI_InMemory_Data_1' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\SB\WideWorldImporters_InMemory_Data_1'
,  MOVE N'WWI_Log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\SB\WideWorldImporters.ldf'
,  STATS = 5, ENABLE_BROKER
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following article which describes how to restore the database with service broker enabled :-[restore - service broker options](https://mattsql.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/service-broker-what-does-a-dba-need-to-know/)

https://mattsql.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/service-broker-what-does-a-dba-need-to-know/